# Can the difference of means be seen as a fulfilled precondition for simple mediation analysis?

Tags: regression, mean, mediation

The preconditions for a simple mediation analysis according to Hayes (2013) are statistically significant associations between X (the independent variable) and M (the mediator) as well as associations between M and Y (the dependent variable). **In the case of a dichotomous independent variable with the values 0 and 1: could a significant difference of the means of M between the two groups 0 and 1 be considered as a fulfilled precondition/significant association, so that carrying out a mediation analysis is justified?**

*My own thoughts on this question: Firstly, the term association confuses me. Unfortunately Hayes doesn’t give a definition of “association”. Other sources that I have consulted yet define association as covariation and link it to correlation and regression. The difference of means isn’t mentioned as a measure of association. But doesn’t the difference of means also indicate covariation in certain cases? For example, I have a dichotomous variable that indicates membership in a trauma survivor or a non-trauma group.  If I find significant differences between the two groups in an outcome like depressive symptoms, I could interpret it as the following: depressive symptoms covary with trauma exposure; therefore the difference of means is an indicator of covariation. Furthermore the non-standardized regression coefficient in a linear regression model with an independent dichotomous variable (values 0,1) is the difference of the means of Y between 0 and 1. The regression coefficient is considered as a measure of association. As a result, in a regression-based simple mediation model with a dichotomous variable as X, the path coefficient from X to M is the difference of the means of M between 0 and 1.*

Thank you for your responses

Answer (score 0):

No that's evidence, or a precondition, of effect modification.

Comment: Thank you AdamO for your response. Let me just paraphrase what you said, so there is no confusion of terms. You say that the difference of means can't be used as evidence to justify the application of a mediaiton analysis?

Comment: @michael correct. In fact, the concept of a "precondition" could be deemphasized. The justification for applying mediation analysis, or any analysis, is because it is part of a question of interest. If such a question is of interest, you should calculate and report the results of the appropriate test.